# Praat - Error when processing Pitch of .wav file: "minimum pitch must not be less than..."

Tags: nlp, speech, linguistics, praat

I've been Praat scripting for only a few weeks now, so bear with me. I'm trying to extract the pitch contours of each spoken word in a corpus of annotated speech data. I can extract the pitch contours of the whole long sound file no problem, and I can chomp the .wav file into smaller .wav files of a single spoken word, but when I try looping through the smaller .wavs I frequently get this error:

> To analyse this Sound, 'minimum pitch' must not be less than [some
>   number].

where that number seems to be pretty arbitrary. 
Is there a good way to dynamically change the parameters for `To Pitch:` based on the minimum pitch for a given .wav?

```
#initialize counter
i = 0

#loop through .wav files
for current_file from 1 to file_count
   i = i + 1
   select Strings list
   filename$ = Get string... current_file
   Read from file... 'source_directory$'/'filename$'
   appendInfoLine: string$(i)+ "/" + string$(file_count) + " " + filename$

   To Pitch: 0.1, 75, 600

   #create pitch file
   pitch_file$ = filename$ - "wav" + "pit"

   #write to pitch file
   no_of_frames = Get number of frames
   for frame from 1 to no_of_frames
       time = Get time from frame number: frame
       pitch = Get value in frame: frame, "Hertz"
       appendFileLine: pitch_file$, "'time','pitch'"
   endfor

endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have figured it out, but if not, try to change the time step from 0.1 to 0.01 or even smaller (To Pitch: 0.01, 75, 600), or make the interval longer if it doesn't affect your analyze.

I got exactly the same error today, and thanks to your description of the duration, I kind of figured out where the problem is. When viewing the pitch line in Praat you can see the data points when zoomed in. The error occurs if the points are less than four within a single interval(don't count the points when fully zoomed into the interval, view the interval leaving small extra spaces when counting ).

The error disappeared when I make the interval a bit longer including a fourth pitch point or set a smaller time step programmatically. I use a python package that accesses to Praat but the process should be similar.
Of course, I would like to hear it if you've got a better solution:)

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the time step works the magic. I had this and got the same error:

```
harmonicity = call(sound, "To Harmonicity (cc)", 0.01, 75, 0.1, 1.0)
```

But on changing it to this (reducing the time step from 0.1 to 0.01), I got my analysis:

```
harmonicity = call(sound, "To Harmonicity (cc)", 0.01, 75, 0.01, 1.0)
```